# Prism 5.0 Interactivity Call Window

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, prism-5

I like the way [Prism 5.0 Interactivity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921081%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) works, but it can just open `UserControls` and `Panels` and such inside a `Window` it creates. So since it cannot place a `Window` inside another `Window` you can't pass a view for it that has `Window` as the root element.

The problem is, when it places my `UserControl` inside the `Window` it created, the `Window` has not a `MinWidth` or `MinHeight` or a `ResizeMode="NoResize"` option to be selected, thus, the user interface becomes horrible.

Are there any ways to control the `Window`'s properties so I can customize it as I want?

PS: It amazes me how a big and important company as Microsoft can release a Best Practices library with stuff missing like that.

---

As requested, here comes a code example:

In order to open a view in a new `Window` in Prism, you have to add this to the current view (the view that's going to invoke the creation of a new `Window` in it's `ViewModel`):

```
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ItemSelectionRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
            <!-- This PopupWindowAction has a custom view defined. When this action is executed the view will be shown inside a new window -->
            <!-- Take into account that the view and its view model are created only once and will be reused each time the action is executed -->
            <prism:PopupWindowAction>
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <views:ItemSelectionView />
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

If you change this `ItemSelectionView` from a `UserControl` to a `Window`, you will get this exception:

[image: Window inside Window Exception]

Since basically Prism will try to place a `Window` inside a `Window` when it creates a new `Window` and a new `ItemSelectionView` and tries to put one inside the other...and `Windows` are suppose to be the root always, but in this case `Window` `ItemSelectionView` will be placed as a child of a new `Window`.

More information about how this works, please go to the link I posted.

---

For now I am using code behind to tweak the window, I check if this `UserControl` is the root of the Window, and only in that case I teak the `Window's` settings (this isn't ideal, but still isn't a violation of MVVM):

```
 private void OnLoaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
    if (parentWindow != null && parentWindow.Content == this)
    {
         parentWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
         parentWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Height;
         parentWindow.MinHeight = this.MinHeight;                
         parentWindow.MinWidth = this.MinWidth;                
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code sample of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty simple solution.

Since the `PopupWindowAction` creates the wrapper windows as instances of the `Window` class, you can apply a default style to the type `Window` in your **app.xaml**.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="500"/>
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
        <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Well, I thought about this...but I have several `Windows` and they are all different, so this won't help a bit unfortunately.